# JS checkbox alert on selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We've been having some fun trying to get checkboxes selection to do things in javascript.

At this point, I copied the code from http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/RFxwp/
And it doesn't work.
I even added in a check for jquery.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WHY</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            if (window.jQuery) {
                alert("jquery enabled");
            } else {
                alert("jquery broken");
            }

            $('#rollDiv :checkbox').click(function () {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        // $this will contain a reference to the checkbox
                        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
                            // the checkbox was checked 
                            alert('checked');
                        } else {
                            // the checkbox was unchecked
                            alert('unchecked');
                        }
                    });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="rollDiv">
            <input checked="checked" type="checkbox">
            <input checked="checked" type="checkbox">
            <input checked="checked" type="checkbox">
            <input checked="checked" type="checkbox">
        </div>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox">
    </body>
</html>
```

Is live here: http://mfurland.w3.uvm.edu/ical/test.html

It validates fine at http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmfurland.w3.uvm.edu%2Fical%2Ftest.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

I am obviously missing *something*, but have no idea what to check. Many thanks for any help.

Comment: I highly encourage you to read the [**jQuery tutorial**](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/). There it says: *"To run code as soon as the document is ready to be manipulated, jQuery has a statement known as the ready event `$( document ).ready(function() { // Your code here. });`"*

Comment: jQuery / Sizzle pseudo selectors always should be preceded by a tag name to prevent the implicit use of the `*` selector which is a potential performance killer. Compare: https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/8M7z4/3/.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rollDiv').find('input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
       alert($(this).is(':checked') ? 'checked' : 'unchecked');
    });
});
```

Looking at the [fiddle you gave as reference](http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/RFxwp/), you can see that in the `Frameworks & Extensions` area on the left sidebar the option `onDomReady` is set. This causes jsfiddle to wrap the provided js code into

```
$(function(){ ... });
```

which is equivalent to

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

and is missing at your [live version](http://mfurland.w3.uvm.edu/ical/test.html).

**Side note**:
While listening for `click` events will work for most users, there are alternative methods to check a checkbox, e.g. on screen readers or programmatically via js. Listening for `change` events catches these cases too and is more secure in almost every case.

Comment: Why is `#rollDiv *:checkbox` a problem?

Comment: You're right it *should* match. But it is a potential performance hit.

Comment: Sure, but the question/problem is not about performance. It would be a good comment IMO.

Comment: Many thanks, especially for explaining why the fiddle I had didn't work. I started with change events, but went to exactly the example for debug purposes, but thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to encapsulate the button click method within `$(document).ready()`, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#rollDiv :checkbox').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        // box  will contain a reference to the checkbox
        if ($this.is(':checked')) {
             // the checkbox was checked 
             alert('checked');
        } else {
             // the checkbox was unchecked
             alert('unchecked');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#rollDiv :checkbox').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    // $this will contain a reference to the checkbox
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        // the checkbox was checked 
        alert('checked');
    } else {
        // the checkbox was unchecked
        alert('unchecked');
    }
});
```

shoud be:

```
$('#rollDiv input:checkbox').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    // $this will contain a reference to the checkbox
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        // the checkbox was checked 
        alert('checked');
    } else {
        // the checkbox was unchecked
        alert('unchecked');
    }
});
```

The ':checkbox' is a shortcode for input[type='checkbox']. It only works if you also pass the input as stated above.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to use `:checkbox` alone: https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/.

Comment: please take a look at the example from the link you posted

Comment: Please read the introduction: *"`$( ":checkbox" )` is equivalent to `$( "[type=checkbox]" )"` [...]"*